# mat-slider reacts strange in a loop when dragging

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I develop a skillDB and i use the mat-slider for display and change the value of a skill. I have two arrays. one for the users and according to a user the skills. So i read in a loop the users and in this loop the skills to a user. In the mat-slider tag i use ngModel to change the value of the skill array when the slider is dragging. The problem is, if the ngModel is added to the tag, the actual AND the next slider of the loop reacts on dragging the slider. The value instead is correct changed in the array. if i delete the ngModel from the mat-slider tag, the slider works fine.

I´ve tried to change the value of the array on dragging by sending them to a function via input=MyFunc(), but it´s still the same behavior.

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0" layout="row">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ post.title }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-action-row>
        <div *ngFor="let value of post.skillValues; let i = index"> 
          {{ skills[i]?.title }}
          <br>
          <mat-slider [(ngModel)]="post.skillValues[i]"  min="0" max="5" step="1" value="{{value}}"></mat-slider>
<!--          <mat-slider (input)="updateSkillArray($event, post, i)" min="0" max="5" step="1" value="{{value}}"></mat-slider>-->
        </div> 
      <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="onSave(post)">SAVE</button>
      <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(post.id)">DELETE</button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p class="info-text mat-body-1" *ngIf="posts.length <= 0">No posts added yet!</p>
```

Comment: I think it will be easier to help out if you have a minimal working demo, (e.g. using Stackblitz).

Comment: I assume `skillValues` is a simple array of numbers? If you change this to be an array of objects, for example `[{value: 2}, {value: 4}]`, and then bind `ngModel` to the `value` property of the object, it works. Not sure why though.